# update an array element in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, multipartform-data, multer

I am trying to update an array element inside a document without changing whole array.

Array elements look like this

[image]

Suppose i have to only update index `1` element's value. For that i have:

1. `_id` of the document
2. index `1`'s value *("optionalImages-624476a7bd4d2bfe6bf86e9a-1-1650025533684.jpeg")*
3. to be updated value *("optionalImages-624476a7bd4d2bfe6bf86e9a-1-1650025534589.jpeg")*.

I think it can be updated by mongodb's `arrayfilters` but i don't get the documentation correctly.
Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query1

- arrayFilters using `$[m]` inside the path to specify the member value that we want to change
- m is the member with value 20, and we set it to 100
  (instead of 20 and 100, put your "....jpg" strings)

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62596f28f7e3c64c6511e187)

```js
update(
{"_id": {"$eq": 1}},
{"$set": {"ar.$[m]": 100}},
{"arrayFilters": [{"m": {"$eq": 20}}])
```

Query2

- pipeline update >= MongoDB 4.2
- uses map on the array to
- find the member with value 20, and replaces it with 100

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62596d72f7e3c64c6511e186)

```js
update(
{"_id": {"$eq": 1}},
[{"$set": 
   {"ar": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$ar",
        "in": {"$cond": [{"$eq": ["$$this", 20]}, 100, "$$this"]}}}}}])
```